# Немогу изменить стиль в Git Bash

Tags: bash, консоль, git-bash

После того как установил тему в Git Bash у меня изменился стиль оформления: появилась дата и время это очень раздражает, теперь я немогу изменить на старую. Как можно это сделать или удалить тему?

[image: вот так выглядить сейчас терминал]

[image: как было раньше]

Comment: так как вы установили, только наоборот :) так сложно помочь мне кажется, опишите свои действия

Comment: просто подскажите как сбросить тему до изначального, я сделал git clone какую то тему и все, у меня тема сменилась теперь хочу просто удалить все темы

Comment: вот есть инструкция https://github.com/sksuryan/git-bash-theme/blob/master/README.md для установки темы, ключевым является мне кажется `Replace the original git-prompt.sh.` то есть вам нужно посмотреть на дату изменения данного файла, и либо где-то найти дефолтный либо переустановить все

Comment: Я попробовал удалить git bash и переустановить не получилось видимо config файл где то хранится) просто так глаза мазолит часики

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/anvn8j/put_git_bash_colour_theme_back_to_their_defaults/ вот тут похоже на вашу проблему

Comment: Спасибо, я просто нашел тот последний конфиг и удалил и все стало на свои места